# Google Maps Autocompletar se Muestra Detrás del ModalPopupExtender ASPX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, autocompletar

Estoy implementando un sitio indexador de direcciones y utilizo Google Maps. El siguiente código de JQuery lee el campo `txEnterStreet`, sin embargo, el autocompletar sale por debajo del AJAX ModalPopupExtender.

```
$(function () {
    $("#txEnterStreet").geocomplete({
        map: ".map_canvas",
        details: "fieldset",
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
        }
    });

    $("#txEnterStreet").bind("geocode:dragged", function (event, latLng) {
        $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
        $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
        $("#reset").show();
    });

    $("#btnFind").click(function () {
        $("#txEnterStreet").trigger("geocode");
    }).click();
});
```

Utilizo el JQuery Geocomplete provisto aquí: [jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/) (repositorio original: [sitio original](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)). La imagen abajo muestra cómo aparece el autocompletar. Como se puede notar, el autocompletar sale por debajo.

Este código HTML es la porción del ModalPopupExtender y el Panel. Todo funciona bien excepto el autocompletar.

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender 
  ID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps" 
  runat="server" 
  PopupControlID="pnlGoogleMaps" 
  DropShadow="false" 
  TargetControlID="lnkFake"
  CancelControlID="btnCloseMap" 
  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground6" 
  BehaviorID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel 
  ID="pnlGoogleMaps" 
  CssClass="modalPopup6" 
  runat="server" 
  Style="top: 6% !important; display:normal;">
  <br />
  <div class="parent" style="text-align: center">
    <span class="child">
      <b>
        <asp:Label 
          ID="lbHydrantInGoogleMaps" 
          runat="server"
          Text="Street Index - Google Maps" 
          Font-Size="X-Large">
        </asp:Label>
      </b>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br />
  <asp:Literal ID="litGetAutocomplete" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <div id="map_containter" style="width: 942px;">

                    <div style="float: left; width: 11%;">
                        <strong>Street Name: </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>

                    <div style="float: left; width: 39%">

                        <input id="txEnterStreet" type="text" class="glow" style="width: 300px" />
                        <input id="btnFind" type="button" value="Find" onclick="ClearDivs()" style="background-color: aqua; width: 50px; font-weight: bold" class="glow"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 15%">
                        <strong>Selected Location:</strong>

                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 14%; text-align: left">
                        <%--<input id="txSelectedStreet" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="glow" style="width: 300px" />--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txSelectedStreet" CssClass="glow" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ShowMap.js"></script>
                <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/StyledMapColor.js"></script>--%>

                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="map_canvasRoute" class="map_canvasRoute">
                      <div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas"> </div>
                      <div id="map_canvas2" class="map_canvas2"> </div>

                      </div>

                    <div id="map_route"></div>
                </div>
                <br />


                <fieldset id="info" style="border: none">
                    <label>Formatted Add.:</label>
                    &emsp;

                    <asp:TextBox ID="formatted_address" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="glow" Width="270px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &emsp;

                    <label>Latitude:</label>
                    &emsp;

                    <asp:TextBox ID="lat" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="glow"></asp:TextBox>
                    &emsp;

                    <label>Longitude:</label>
                    &emsp;

                    <asp:TextBox ID="lng" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="glow"></asp:TextBox>
                </fieldset>

                <br />
                    Calc. route from: 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txStartvalue" placeholder="Enter a 'From' location" CssClass="glow" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                <input id="btnCloneFrom" type="button" value="Clone" onclick="Clone2From()" title="Clone street name here" class="glow" style="background-color: #99FF99" />
                &emsp;
                    to: 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txEndvalue" CssClass="glow" placeholder="Enter a 'To' location" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                <input id="btnCloneTo" type="button" value="Clone" onclick="Clone2To()" title="Clone street name here" class="glow" style="background-color: #99FF99"/>

                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="btnSearchLocation" value="Get Route" onclick="return calcRoute()" title="Click for location" style="background-color: #FF9900; width: 100px; font-weight: bold" class="glow" />
                &emsp;

                &emsp;
                <input type="button" id="btnClearTextFields" value="Clear" onclick="javascript: ClearTextboxes()" title="Clear fields for new search" style="background-color: #FFFFCC; width: 100px; font-weight: bold" class="glow" />
                &emsp;

                <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="TEST" onclick="return test()" title="Re-write Previous Location" style="background-color: #6EA2DE; width: 100px; font-weight: bold; display:none;" class="glow" />
                &emsp;

                <asp:Button ID="btnCloseMap" runat="server" CssClass="glow" Text="Close" ToolTip="Close Map Window" Width="100px" BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFFFF" OnClientClick="OnCloseClear()" />
                <input id="txSendAMessage" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="glow" style="border-style: none; font-size: small; color: #FF0000; font-style: normal; font-family: Calibri; width: 532px" />

                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbMapsWarning" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC3300" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>

            </asp:Panel>
```

[image: Autocompletar debajo]

Answer (score 1):

Después de investigar por varios días, la solución parece simple. En mi caso, fue necesario agregar `z-index` en el CSS, quedando así:

```
.modalBackground6 {
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    /*z-index: 9999 !important;*/
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

/*for the panel*/
.modalPopup6 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: Black;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    width: 950px;
    height: 720px;

    /*z-index: 9999 !important;*/
    z-index: !important;

}
```

Esto modificaría, entonces, esto:

```
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlGoogleMaps" DropShadow="false" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
        CancelControlID="btnCloseMap" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground6" BehaviorID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlGoogleMaps" CssClass="modalPopup6" runat="server" Style="top: 6% !important; display:none;">
```

Aquí una imagen: [image: Autcompletar funcionando en ModalPopupExtender]

Comment: Inquietud: la imagen que colocaste en tu pregunta es diferente a la imagen de tu respuesta. ¿es un diseño diferente?.

Comment: En cierto sentido. Utilizo el autocompletar en 3 textboxes diferentes. El primero lo puse allí para prueba y ver qué era lo que sucedía. Fue cuando me di cuenta que el autocompletar sí aparecía, pero por debajo.